# Validate end_date is bigger than start_date in custom action of Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I have a `start_date` and `end_date` fields in `save_related` action of my Django Admin. I want to assign an error to `end_date` when it is bigger than `start_date`.

I have been looking docs, but don't find an example about that. Here is what i have tried so far:

My django admin code:

```
@admin.register(models.Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        obj = form.instance
        # Check validations
        start_date = obj.start
        end_date = obj.end
        if end_date < start_date:
            msg = u"End date should be greater than start date."
            self._errors["end_date"] = self.error_class([msg])
            return
         ...
```

But this code have this error: 'EventAdmin' object has no attribute 'error_class'
How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please include some code that you have tried so far? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I updated my questions with some codes.

Comment: I have the same error, did you solve it?

Comment: @oshingc I used ValidationError in `clean` function in `model.py` file, not admin.py.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

  def clean(self):
        # Check validations
        if end_date < start_date:
            raise ValidationError({'end': ['End date should be greater than start date.']})
```

Please refer these codes:
-  [linke](https://github.com/ninjadev999/google_calendar_events_manager/blob/334a2557fb817633528bcc212d99b86d222c88cb/events/models.py)

Answer (score 0):

```
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CourseForm, self).clean()
        start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('start_date')
        end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('end_date')
        if end_date < start_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("End date should be greater than start date.")
        return cleaned_data

class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CourseForm
```